# Inverse Fourier-Stieltjes transform of $1$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, fourier-analysis

Let $S(x) = \text{sgn}(x)/2$ for $x \ne 0$ and $S(x) = 0$ for $x = 0$.
Then its Fourier-Stieltjes transform is $\hat{S}(k) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i k x} dS(x) = 1$.
I tried to evaluate the inversion formula. $S(x)$ should be recovered by the formula
$$
S(0) + \lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\lambda}^\lambda \hat{S}(k)\frac{1-e^{-i k x}}{i k}dk = \lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\lambda}^\lambda \frac{1-e^{-i k x}}{i k}dk.
$$
However, I don't have any clue how to evaluate the integral. Even I cannot see how the integral makes a discontinuous function. How can I evaluate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
  \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda}\frac{e^{-ikx}-1}{k}dk
    & = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{0}^{\lambda}\frac{e^{-ikx}-1}{k}dk+\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\lambda}^{0}\frac{e^{-ikx}-1}{k}dk \\
    & = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{0}^{\lambda}\frac{e^{-ikx}-1}{k}dk+\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lambda}^{0}\frac{e^{ikx}-1}{k}dk \\
    & = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{0}^{\lambda}\frac{e^{-ikx}-e^{ikx}}{k}dk \\
    & = -\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\lambda}\frac{\sin(kx)}{k}dk \\
    & = -\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\lambda x}\frac{\sin(l)}{l}dl
\end{align}
If $x > 0$, the above tends to
$$
    -\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(l)}{l}dl = -\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\pi}{2} = -\frac{1}{2}.
$$
If $x < 0$, then it tends to the negative of that value. Somehow I'm off by a negative.

Comment: The off by a negative error was from my mistake. The formula I wrote had the mistake. I corrected it.